# How would I convert this to an Alamofire Parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, get-request

Wondering how I would make this into an Alamofire Parameter.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"post":{"$inQuery":{"where":{"image":{"$exists":true}},"className":"Post"}}}' \
  https://YOUR.PARSE-SERVER.HERE/1/classes/Comment
```

The part that's confusing is the `--data-urlencode`

Here's what I got so far:

```
let params: Parameters = [
    "where": ["post": ["$inQuery" : "where": ]],
]
```

I'm stuck, do I keep nesting `Parameters`?

Comment: @danypata Not a duplicate because I'm not trying to use in Postman. I am trying to convert to Alamofire Parameters.

Comment: If you have the request in postman you can select code output and Swift as the language and it will show you the swift code for the parameters

Comment: @Scriptable Yes though it's not in Alamofire format.

Comment: Doesn't need to be, the parameters are just a dictionary object, so it will give you the dictionary you need.